# Get screen layout of multiple screens on linux/Gnome

Tags: python, linux, bash, screen, multiple-monitors

I am trying to create an application for multiple screens however I so far cannot find a way to locate the secondary screens position (relative to the primary screen by x and y coordinates).

I prefer to use python or bash (via libraries/frameworks are fine). I also checked with xorg.conf and it doesn't reflect my current screen setup.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (default Gnome 2 I believe), using compiz as the window manager. So to repeat, my question is how to get the screen layout (coordinates relative to primary screen) of all the monitors preferably by python or bash.

Comment: Run xrandr and see if you could parse data from it with subprocess.

Comment: Never mind it is a python module called python-randr. A don't know anything about it. But I suppose it would help you.

Comment: Doh. Python-xrandr of course. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I used Pyqt instead. Here is some code...

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QPixmap
desktop = QApplication.desktop()
screenRect = desktop.screenGeometry(1)   #2nd monitor
print screenRect.x(), screenRect.y()   #returns the x and y of that screen
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python binding solution

So, from here you can download the xrandr bindings for python: https://launchpad.net/python-xrandr

```
# Import the module
from xrandr import xrandr

# Get a screen object to work with
screen = xrandr.get_current_screen()

# Get the active output objects as a list
active_outputs = [o for o in screen.get_outputs() if o.is_active()]
```

This was as far as I got playing around a little. I hope it will get you started :-) I only have one screen connected right now...

## Parsing data solution

The other solution, as I mentioned in my comment above is to parse the output of the command `xrandr` it looks like it should be pretty simple from just taking a glance at it...

Comment: It seems that I could only use xrandr in bash. Python binding doesn't give me the positions, not even screen.print_info(), can you find it? Also output[0]._x and ._y will always return 0 regardless of screen position.

Comment: Strange. But whatever does the job works and qt seemed to have a good syntax also (python-xrandr did'nt). But just so you know, these days xorg is only used for setting resolution and so initially (if it contains data). xrandr is whats used then.

Comment: This line is generating an error message: `ett samband mellan hur mycket N sovit senaste dygnet och`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Oppsie. That line had absolutely nothing to do with the code. I must have pasted something by mistake in there. I will edit it out of the answer, but I have no idea if this 8 year old answer is still valid.

Comment: Sorry I didn't test your answer I used `gdk` instead along with OS calls to `xrandr --listactivemonitors | grep ...` etc